# Webclient for mbox files

Tags: imap, web-applications, mbox

I have 20 OVH mail accounts. Whit [imapbackup](https://github.com/rcarmo/imapbackup) i create mbox file for each my account on a local server. To read the files i need to download the folder then import to Thunderbird. Is there a easy way to show ALL mbox using a web client ( like roundcube) whitout install dovecot and similar mail server?

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1285736